# Space of bounded functions with infinity norm is metric space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $B[a,b]$ be the set of all bounded functions on $[a,b]\subset \mathbb R$. So I want to show that $(B[a,b], d_\infty)$ is a metric space. And then determine whether or not it is complete.

Now, consider two functions: a discontinuous function $f$ defined only at one point, say, $a$. And a discontinuous function $g$ defined only at one point, say, $b$. Then how is $d_\infty(f,g) = \sup\limits_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x)-g(x)|$ defined? Or what am I missing  here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is only defined at one point, then $g$ is **not** a bounded function on $[a,b]$ (because it is not a function on $[a,b]$, it's a function on $\{b\}$) and so it is not in $B[a,b]$. So $d_{\infty}(f,g)$ is not defined.

Comment: But what if $g$ is discontinuous on a subinterval of $[a,b]$? Does it become a function not on $[a,b]$? Then does this mean that all bounded functions on $[a,b]$ must be continuous?

Comment: @sequence No, the functions can lack continuity throughout - but they must be defined on all of $[a,b]$

Comment: @sequence No, I didn't say that. A function on $[a,b]$ simply means that $f(x)$ is defined **for every element $x\in[a,b]$**. Plenty of functions on $[a,b]$ can be bounded, but not continuous.

Comment: @sequence The problem with your example isn't that your $g$ is not *continuous*, it is that your $g$ is not **defined** on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Do you mean that $f$ has to be defined on all of $[a,b]$ except possibly at finitely many points?

Comment: @sequence It means $f$ has to be defined on all of $[a,b]$. Period. It's a **function on $[a,b]$**, after all. It has to be defined on all of the points.